# How to iterate through instance of a parent class?

Tags: python, loops, class

I'm trying to iterate through a dictionary object initialized in a parent class, and append it to an instance in a child class. However, when I try to iterate through it, I receive...

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

...when running `for key in self.inv`

```
class Inventory:
    '''Create inventory class'''
    def __init__(self, inv):
        self.inv = inv

 class Cart(Inventory):
    '''Customer shopping cart class'''
    def __init__(self, cart):
        self.cart = cart
        self.inv = super(Inventory).__init__()

    
    def scanning(self, inv):
        Inventory.displayInv(inv)
        print(vars(inv))
        scanned = 0
        while scanned != "pay":
            scanned = input("Input a barcode to scan or type 'pay' to pay: ")
            if scanned.isdigit():
                scanned = int(scanned)
            for key in self.inv:         #THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
                if key == scanned:
                    print(self.inv[key])
                    Cart.updateCart(self.cart, self.inv, key)
                    total_price, total_items = Cart.updateTotals(self)
                    Cart.displayCart(self, total_items, total_price)
                    break
```

Comment: `Inventory.__init__()` does not return anything. Yet you are assigning it to `self.inv`. Also note, `Inventory.__init__(self, inv)` requires a parameter. You aren't passing that when you call it from the child.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This code has an `IndentationError`, but it seems to be a basic typo. After fixing that, there's no instantiation of `Cart` and no call to `scanning()`, so it's not clear what you're expecting to happen. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code, any example input, expected output, and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). You can [edit]. If you want more tips, see [ask].

Comment: @Mark Actually, `Inventory.__init__` is never called. `super(Inventory)` means search *after* `Inventory` in the MRO, so it's actually `object.__init__`. But still, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Yeah, good point @wjandrea, I suppose that explains why there's not an error from calling it with no `inv` argument.